# Open air/flex aplications inside any browser window

Tags: apache-flex, browser, air

I've been searching around web and so far found many tutorials/docs on how to install or open air application from a web page. This just opens a new AIR-browser window and that's not what I'm looking for. I'd like it be opened inside a browser frame (even if downloaded first) much like a plain swf file.

I know air file is more or less plain zip, so maybe I could unpack it? What AIR features shouldn't I use for this to work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? AIR apps are not meant to run in browsers, they're desktop applications. Any AIR-only API calls will not be available via the browser.

Comment: The point is I'd like to have one application (or at least similar application) for user that want to install the app and for those that just want to play one minute with it. And I don't want to actually write to apps - call me lazy ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Impossible.  Air is a separate application.  It's like saying "I want Microsoft Word to open within a browser frame".

Comment: To my knowledge technically AIR is run inside a browser - it's just an Adobe browser. I just want it to run in a different browser even if with some plugin or without using some specific functions.

Comment: Air is run within a runtime, not a browser.  That is unless you use the javascript way of doing Air.  And no, you can't have it run within a browser.  If you want that, why not just use Flex?

Comment: I've already made HTML+JS+Flash apps packaged inside AIR. And so I was thinking about sort of a backward process. I've heard AIR is using Webkit for rendering HTML, JS, Flash and just a few more technologies more then you're average browser so I would still say it's technically is a browser (just not really used for browsing ;-)). Oh and BTW - you can display Word documents inside a browser window.

Comment: displaying the document != having the program run within the window.  Again, I think what you want is just use Flash/Flex which can be run in a browser.